# UI-grid net::ERR_INVALID_URL while displaying base64 image conditionally based on COL_FIELD

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, angular-ui-grid

I am using  ui-grid to display a table in which I am showing avatar as the first column.  The avatar image is base64 image displayed conditionally as per col_field value from the back-end.

If the col_field is null then display the default image which is in base64 (available in the scope) else the image from the col_field itself.

**issue**:

*The default image is available in the scope and its displayed correctly but I get the console error  `net::ERR_INVALID_URL`*

**error** :

> data:image/jpg;base64,{{COL_FIELD!=null ? COL_FIELD :
>   'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhE…NqS+jMdu/p7D8dz14x323NdD+uW/+WonqAL75HX/wswAH3/1hmUDbAiAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'}}
>   net::ERR_INVALID_URL

here is the code snippet

```
columnDefs : [
{
    field : 'profilImage',
    cellTemplate : '<div class="thumbnail-image-list" > \
                    <img 
                         style="vertical-align:middle;" 
                         width="16" height="16" 
                         alt="{{row.entity.name}}"
                         src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{COL_FIELD!=null ? COL_FIELD : \'' + $scope.defaultImageHexCode + '\'}}"/>
                   </div>',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using interpolation, bind the attribute using `ng-src` instead of `src`.